# file_get_contents appends data when downloading a binary file

Tags: php

I wrote a function that allows me to send HTTP GET requests in PHP:

```
function get_HTTPS_page_with_version($url, $hostname, $use_HTTP_1_0 = false, &$headers = NULL, $follow_redirect = true, $use_SSL = true) {
  $context = Array(
    "http" => Array(
      "method" => "GET",
      "ignore_errors" => true,
      "follow_location" => $follow_redirect,
      "user_agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36",
      "header" => "Accept-language: en")
  );

  if ($use_SSL) {
    $context["ssl"] = Array(
      "peer_name" => $hostname,
      "SNI_server_name" => $hostname,
      "verify_peer_name" => false,
      "verify_peer" => false);
  }

  if (!$use_HTTP_1_0) {
    $context["http"]["protocol_version"] = "1.1";
    $context["http"]["header"] .= "\r\nHost: $hostname".
                                  "\r\nConnection: close";
  }

  $page = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($context));
  $responseCode = get_HTTP_response_code($http_response_header);
  $headers = $http_response_header;

  return Array($responseCode, $page);
}
```

The issue is that when I use this function to get a specific file (which is [Verisign Certificate Revocation List](http://sb.symcb.com/sb.crl)), it appends some chars at the beginning:

```
6639 6361 0a0d --> f9 ca \n\r
```

and at the end of the file:

```
0a0d 0d30 0d0a 000a --> \n\r \r0 \r\n NUL\n
```

I compared files obtained manually using Wget and with this function, and also at network level using Wireshark, and I can confirm that the file sent by the server is the same in both cases.

I also don't have the problem for [Thawte CRL](http://ti.symcb.com/ti.crl)

Does anyone have an idea about what might cause this behavior?

**EDIT**

Verisign CRL changed and other bytes are added by file_get_contents than the ones that I listed above, but the result is still the same --> The file is not the same when downloaded by this function than manually using wget.

**EDIT 2**

- There is no problem when I set `$use_HTTP_1_0 = true`.
- There is no problem when I add header `Accept-Encoding: gzip,
  deflate` (except that I get a gz file and that I'd prefer to avoid
  this :))
- There is still a problem when I only change `Connection` from `close`
  to `Keep-Alive`

Comment: The same happens if you do not provide your own headers? Also, are the response headers the same for all tools?

Comment: @cen I made some more tests based upon your comment and it appears that there is no problem if I use HTTP/1.0 instead of 1.1. I'll edit my question with this finding.

Comment: You can't use Keep-ALive with Http 1.0. Anyway, if I do a GET request to your crl via Postman I also get non UTF-8 chars in the beginning. Is the CRL file supposed to be  text file or a binary one? My guess is that maybe the server encodes some extra info depending on the agent or request headers or whatever. Unfortunately I am not an expert on CRLs so this is just a blind guess.

Comment: You could also try to decode wget and php file with openssl into plain text and see what the actual difference is (if any): ```openssl crl -inform DER -text -in sb.crl``` Edit: apparently crl is in DER format which has binary data so it's not a plain text file.

Comment: @cen thank you. I know that `Connection` header is not part of HTTP/1.0, but I tried it with HTTP/1.1 to see if that was the point :) Indeed CRL is in DER format which is a binary format. `openssl crl` command won't work with my function as the result I get is not a valid DER file. And finally I don't think server sends a different file depending on client's signature as I cannot see the added bytes in my Wireshark captures.

Comment: Well, the only thing left that I can think of that gzip and deflate work it must be the plain text that is causing it. file_get_contents() reads file into a text string. So when text string is saved to a file, probably with UTF8 encoding, all hell breaks loose: http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/